# Cheat codes won't work in Grand Theft Auto 3

Tags: cheats, ps2, grand-theft-auto-iii

I was playing Grand Theft Auto 3 and entering cheat codes when all of a sudden the cheat codes stopped working! I would type one in and nothing would happen.

What's going on?

Comment: What platform?  GT3 has been ported to a half dozen different systems.  It seems very likely this is a platform specific bug/quirk.

Comment: oh ya sorry, ps2

Comment: Is it still broken after you restart the game?

Comment: ya I did try to restart it